# python shell becomes unusable after suspend (ctrl-Z) and 'fg' command

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard, iterm, zsh

When I suspend python with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and try to get it back with `fg`, I cannot use the python interactive command prompt anymore. Pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key produces ^M on the screen, <kbd>Esc</kbd> produces ^[ and even <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> doesn't work (it just displays ^C). I have to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> again and `kill %1`.

Any guesses as to what's wrong?

I'm using zsh with iTerm2 on MacOS Catalina.

I've included a screenie below.

[image]

P.S. I know cross-posting is frowned upon, but I didn't get any responses on StackOverflow so I have copy-pasted my question here. Google has been unhelpful, as I cannot search special characters (such as ^M).

Comment: Does this behavior occur with Terminal.app?

Comment: @MarcWilson Yes it does.

Comment: It doesn't happen here.  Who's python is that?  Reaching for straws, if you launch the shell without the custom config, does it still occur?

Comment: @MarcWilson I removed my ~/.zshrc and the problem went away. Then I narrowed it down to the [z plugin](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/z). I have commented it out in my .zshrc and it's fine now.
I'm not well-versed in shell scripts and unix in general. So I had no idea where to start. Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You should use precedence percentage symbol `%` with along with the job number while switching between the foreground and background jobs.
Example: `fg %1`

See the [zsh manual](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Jobs-_0026-Signals.html#Jobs-_0026-Signals)

Comment: That didn't make a difference. The issue persisted. I've identified the "z" plugin as the culprit though.

Answer (score 0):

The offender was the [z plugin](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/z). I commented it out in my ~/.zshrc from `plugins = ( ... )` and it got fixed. I wasn't really using that plugin anyway so it's fine. Thank you Marc Wilson for the troubleshooting pointer.